Process started by task scheduler not visible in task manager
I'm using Windows 10. A script (stored in a .bat file) starts a process. If the script is executed directly (say, by double clicking), the process is visible in the task manager. However, if the script is started by the task scheduler, the process is started and running (as can be seen by executing  the command tasklist), but the process isn't visible in the task manager.
Question: Is it possible to configure the task schedule such that the process is visible in the task manager?

When you use Task Scheduler to run a script stored in a .bat file on Windows 10, you might notice that the process it initiates doesn't show up in the task manager. This occurs because Task Scheduler operates under different settings than when you manually execute the script. To ensure the process is visible:
Make sure your task in Task Scheduler is set to run with your user account's permissions and that the "Run with highest privileges" option is checked. This guarantees it has the necessary authority.
Also, check the Actions tab of the task to verify that your script (.bat file) is correctly specified.
By adjusting these settings, you can help ensure that the process initiated by your script through Task Scheduler is visible in the task manager while it runs.

Thank you very much, it worked.
